# How to give PHP/Exec more privileges?

Tags: php, nginx, command-line-interface

I have simple command which looks like this:

```
$command = sprintf('cd %s && node app > /dev/null 2>&1 &', $this->get('node_dir'));

exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

The main problem is that it's not working from the browser... If I execute it from console or `php-cli` it works fine, but not from the browser.

As I understood the problem is that the user `www-data` doesn't have enough privileges to start it. How can I fix it?

Command doesn't require `sudo`.

Comment: this is the last thing you should think to do :)

Answer (score 0):

The options are two:

1. make php run with higher privilege (but just nope)
2. give www-data the privilege to executing that app. Just add www-data to a
   group that can run the scripts in that directory

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what you need to do without more details, but the short of it is that fixing permission problems with PHP is exactly the same as fixing any permission problems in linux.  There are likely two places you might run into permission problems with this command:

1. cd
2. node

It is possible for a directory with restrictive permissions to prevent a given user from CD'ing to it in the first place.  The easiest way to check this is to change the ownership of the given directory (if possible) to be www-data:

chown www-data:www-data /path/to/directory

The other issue is that node may not have execute privileges for your user.  You'll have to check to see whether the execute permissions for your node command allow anyone to execute, or just a limited set of users/groups.  This is easier or harder depending on whether or not the node command is installed in the folder in question or installed globably on the system.  You can check that by CD'ing to the directory yourself and running:

which node

It is probably global, in which case all users probably have execute permissions to it.

You can also consider changing the user that PHP runs under, although this comes with its own baggage.  The way to do that depends on how PHP is running (apache, PHP-FPM, etc), so I can't give anymore hints there, but it is something you could look into.  If PHP runs as a more privileged user, then some of these permissions issues may go away, but you are also less protected if someone finds a remote-code execution vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if node is trying to do something privileged.  It might be helpful to know exactly what the error is.  Do you have a detailed error message?  In your command at the moment you are dumping the error log to /dev/null, which means you are specifically throwing away the error. It might be necessary to post it, since the CD command is fine and my guess is that www-data probably has access to execute the node command.  So you may have to rely on node to get more error details to debug this.

Comment: You certainly can change the user for PHP-FPM.  It is very easy, but depends on your system.  You want to find your www.conf configuration file.  In my case it is here:

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Remember that there are real security implications to doing this.  Also when you are in your www.conf file, keep in mind that there are a separate (but similar) set of configuration settings called listen.owner and listen.group.  These are related to the unix socket that PHP sometimes communicates over, and you probably don't want to change those.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the commands to a shell script, change the owner of the script to some "powerful" user, allow execute privileges of the script to all users and **set setuid bit**.

This way any user can launch the script, including www-data but, with the setuid bit set, it will execute as if the owner launched it, with permissions of the owner.

In PHP you would then call

```
$command = sprintf('myscript.sh %s', $this->get('node_dir'));
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

myscript.sh should take the first parameter and do what you want with it, something like this (**UNTESTED** and I am not good at shell scripting!)

```
cd $1 && node app > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Note the `$1`: that's where you will find the node_dir id

you can then assign ownership with `chown` and allow execution and set the setuid bit with `chmod`

```
sudo chmod 4755 myscript.sh
```

Info about the setuid:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

**Be careful of what you put in the script if any user can execute it with stronger privileges!**

I do not endorse this as a secure way, especially not knowing what can end inside the node_dir parameter!

**P.S.:**

You could also write the script in PHP and then call

```
$command = sprintf('myscript.php %s', $this->get('node_dir'));
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

This way you are passing execution to the CLI PHP. If the setuid bit is set, permissions are changed to the owner of the script. Script should start with #!/usr/bin/php or correct "shebang" for your PHP and made executable with `chmod` (`sudo chmod 4755 myscript.php`)